# Unable to build DatabaseInformation - Multiple Datasources Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm quite new on spring boot, and i'm trying to set multiple datasources with validation from JPA, but i'm getting the following error:

```
Unable to build DatabaseInformation
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDatabaseInformation(Helper.java:140) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.doValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:61) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'concentrador.pg_class' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1218) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.executeQuery(ProxyStatement.java:111) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.initializeSequences(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.<init>(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDatabaseInformation(Helper.java:132) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    ... 29 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

here is my `application.properties` file

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://<ip>:<port>/<database>

spring.datasource.driver-class-name = org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username = <username>
spring.datasource.password = <password>

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect

spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true

spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

spring.jpa.show-sql = true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = validate

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

flyway.local.locations.classpath = resources/db/migration/

concentrador.datasource.jdbc-url = jdbc:mysql://<ip>:<port>/<database>?useSSL=false

concentrador.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

concentrador.datasource.username = <user>
concentrador.datasource.password = <password>

concentrador.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use-jdbc-metadata-defaults = false

concentrador.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

concentrador.datasource.testWhileIdle = true

concentrador.datasource.validation-query = SELECT 1

concentrador.jpa.show-sql = true

concentrador.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = validate

concentrador.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

concentrador.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

#OTHER SETTINGS
```

Here is my First Datasource Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
    basePackages = {"com.my.package.datasource"}
)
public class DataSourceLocalConfig {
  @Value("${spring.datasource.validation-query}")
  private String validationQuery;

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "dataSource")
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
  public DataSource dataSource(DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties) {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create(dataSourceProperties.getClassLoader())
        .type(HikariDataSource.class)
        .driverClassName(dataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName())
        .url(dataSourceProperties.getUrl())
        .username(dataSourceProperties.getUsername())
        .password(dataSourceProperties.getPassword())
        .build();
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
  entityManagerFactory(
      EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
      @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource
  ) {
    return builder
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .packages("com.my.package.datasource.domain")
        .persistenceUnit("datasource")
        .properties(singletonMap("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate"))
        .build();
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "flyway")
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "flyway.local")
  public Flyway flyway(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    Flyway flyway = Flyway.configure().dataSource(dataSource).load();
    flyway.migrate();
    return flyway;
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
      @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory
          entityManagerFactory
  ) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
  }
}
```

Here is my Second Datasource Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = DataSourceProperties.class)
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactoryConcentrador",
    transactionManagerRef = "transactionManagerConcentrador",
    basePackages = {"com.my.package.concentrador"})
public class DataSourceConcentradorConfig {

  @Value("${concentrador.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect}")
  private String dialect;

  @Value("${concentrador.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy}")
  private String naming;

  @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactoryConcentrador")
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "concentrador.jpa")
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
      EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
      @Qualifier("dataSourceConcentrador") DataSource dataSource) {

    return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.my.package.concentrador.domain")
        .persistenceUnit("concentrador")
        .properties(singletonMap("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate"))
        .properties(singletonMap("concentrador.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect", dialect))
        .properties(singletonMap("concentrador.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy", naming))
        .build();
  }

  @Bean(name = "dataSourceConcentrador")
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "concentrador.datasource")
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }

  private Properties additionalProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.ddl-auto","none");

    return properties;
  }


  @Bean(name = "transactionManagerConcentrador")
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
      @Qualifier("entityManagerFactoryConcentrador") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
  }

}
```

Here is my Main Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication()
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {PdvMovelApplication.class, Jsr310JpaConverters.class})
@ComponentScan({"com.my.package", "com.my.package.config", "com.my.package"})
public class MyApplicationApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(PdvMovelApplication.class, args);
  }

}
```

I'm also using flyway for just the primary datasource.
Thank You!

Comment: The exception states "Table 'concentrador.pg_class' doesn't exist". Does this table exist in the other (DataSourceLocalConfig) database?

Comment: It seems the "concentrador" datasource is not configured properly.  It is using mysql driver to access "concentrador.pg_class" which is a Postgress table.

Comment: I would suggest not using the 'spring.datasource' or 'spring.jpa' properties namespace at all because the Spring datasource auto config classes are looking at that namespace.  I would use a properties namespace for each datasource so that you have full control over the datasource configs.